# $f: \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and $f(\alpha x) = \alpha^2f(x)$, then $x \cdot \nabla f(x) = 2 f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Assume that $f: \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and $f(\alpha x) = \alpha^2f(x)$ for all $x\neq 0$ and $\alpha > 0$. Then I want to prove that $x \cdot \nabla f(x) = 2 f(x)$ when $x$ is nonzero.

I applied Mean value theorem in several variables and tried some linearity tricks but I could not prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiate both sides of the equation $f(\alpha x) = \alpha^2 f(x)$ with respect to $\alpha$ (using the chain rule for the left-hand side). This results in $x \cdot \nabla f(\alpha x) = 2\alpha f(x)$. Evaluate at $\alpha = 1$ to get the result.

Comment: More generally, suppose $f(tx)=t^p f(x)$. Then $x\cdot \nabla f(tx)=pt^{p-1}f(x)$ so $x\nabla f(x)=p f(x)$. The converse is also true.

Comment: How did you get from $f(tx)$ to $x \nabla f(tx)$?

Comment: @gtoques by the chain rule, $\dfrac{d}{dt}[f(tx)] = x\cdot (\nabla f)(tx)$.