# gradient of C1 function problem

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

Let φ : $\mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$
function such that $∀t ∈ \mathbb{R}$ we have $φ(tx) = t^{42}φ(x)$. Prove that
$∀x ∈ R^n$,   $x·∇φ(x) = 42φ(x)$.

If someone could help me out with this problem that'd be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$f: \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and $f(\alpha x) = \alpha^2f(x)$, then $x \cdot \nabla f(x) = 2 f(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043143/f-mathbbr2-0-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-continuously-differentiable-an) – substitute $2$ by $42$ ...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. On this site you are expected to show what you have tried so far to solve the problem, and ask a specific question about it. Just asking for general help won't be of much use to you.